# PHPUnit Assert True One (1)

Tags: php, phpunit, assertions

I am looking at PHPUnit and the following has me wondering. Does or doesn't PHPUnit handle int. 1's and 0's as boolean? In my current testing, it doesn't.

Example: `$this->assertTrue(preg_match('/asdf/', 'asdf'));`

In my testing this fails, as preg_match() is returning int 1 or 0 and only bool false if there is an error.

I take it the following works, obviously, since comparisons always return bool. `$this->assertTrue(preg_match('/asdf/', 'asdf') === 1);`

Am I missing something in my preg_match, or my assertion to make it.... less strict?

EDIT:
Does assertTrue require types to match? Is there any way to make the assertion less strict?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

PHP has separate `boolean` type, its values of `TRUE` and `FALSE` (case-insensitive constants) are not identical to integer values of 1 and 0.

When you use strict comparison (`===`), it does not work: `TRUE !== 1` and `FALSE !== 0`.

When you use type juggling, `TRUE` is converted to 1 and `FALSE` is converted to 0 (and, vice versa, 0 is converted to `FALSE`, any other integer is converted to `TRUE`). So, `TRUE == 1` and `FALSE == 0`.

In PHPUnit, `assertTrue` and `assertFalse` are type-dependent, strict checks. `assertTrue($x)` checks whether `TRUE === $x`, it is the same as `assertSame(TRUE, $x)`, and not the same as `assertEquals(TRUE, $x)`.

In your case, one possible approach would be to use explicit type casting:

```
$this->assertTrue((boolean)preg_match('/asdf/', 'asdf'));
```

However, PHPUnit happens to have dedicated assertion for checking string against regular expression:

```
$this->assertRegExp('/asdf/', 'asdf');
```

Answer (score 5):

Please do not use a bunch of `assertTrue` or `assertFalse` checks with the real logic embedded in a complicated function call when there are more specific test functions available.

PHPUnit has a very vast set of assertions that are really helpful in the case they are not met. They give you a bunch of context of what went wrong, which aids you in debugging.

To check for a regular expression, use `assertRegExp()` (see http://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertRegExp)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but definitely a worthy comment. Thank you, noted.

Comment: `assertTrue` does check for a real `true` value, not something "truthy" as "1".

Comment: To be more specific, I understand what you are saying as: `assertTrue` in PHPUnit does a "triple-equal" comparison, and not a "double-equal" comparison. (See `var_dump(1 == true);` and `var_dump(1 === true);` The first comes back true and the second comes back false, as a "triple-equals" also matches type. Thus is my question. I'll edit the original to be as specific.

Comment: Please note that starting with PHPUnit version 9.1 `assertRegExp` has been deprecated in favour of `assertMatchesRegularExpression` (see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/4086).

Answer (score 0):

While OP's example isn't the best, sometimes one does just want to test whether a given value can be coerced to true. For instance, when passing a value to a boolean column in MySQL, most ORMs will accept a boolean, a numeric string or an integer.

To do this, you can create a custom constraint:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\Constraint\Constraint;

/**
 * @no-named-arguments Parameter names are not covered by the backward compatibility promise for PHPUnit
 */
final class CanBeCoercedToTrue extends Constraint
{
    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the constraint.
     */
    public function toString(): string
    {
        return 'can be coerced to true';
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates the constraint for parameter $other. Returns true if the
     * constraint is met, false otherwise.
     *
     * @param mixed $other value or object to evaluate
     */
    protected function matches(mixed $other): bool
    {
        return ((bool)$other) === true;
    }
}
```

You can use it in an assertion like this:

```
$this->assertThat('1', new CanBeCoercedToTrue());
```

You can also use the constraint elsewhere. For instance:

```
$mockCollection->expects($this->exactly(2))
    ->method('addAttributeToFilter')
    ->with($this->equalTo('is_active'), new CanBeCoercedToTrue());
```